# How to change elements attribute via clicking on another element in CSS

Tags: html, css, click, margin, padding

I inserted a button in header of page and I want change padding and margin of another element when a user clicks on this button. I used this code but didn't work:

```css
a:clicked
{
    #header
    {
        padding:0 40px 0 40px !important;
    }
}
```

In css docs, programmers use `@` symbol at begin of their code. Can I use that? How?

Comment: What you describe is simply not possible by means of css. The reason is that there is no "clicked state" after a click css can operate on. You need to use javascript to caputure the click event on the anchor and set a class "clicked". Then you can use a selector for that class and do the above.

Comment: `a:hover` or `a:active` instead?

Answer (score 0):

CSS has no mechanism for giving your styles "state." It's difficult to make decisions in CSS based on "The user clicked a button," etc.

Difficult, but not impossible. One thing you could do is change the button to a checkbox and use the `:checked` selector. Another option is to hide the checkbox and make the button a label for it; this is known as the [CSS checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

The usual way, though, is to use Javascript to add/remove a class from an element when a button is clicked, then style based on the existence of that class. This is probably more maintainable since it doesn't require hacks to your HTML. Note that it won't work for users who have blocked Javascript.